# Upcoming moderator elections

Tags: discussion, election, moderation

As a heads up, we're going to be holding a diamond moderator election pretty soon for the Emacs Stack Exchange site. I wanted to take this opportunity to explain what will be happening and how you can participate.

### What do diamond moderators do?

Broadly speaking, moderators handle things out of the ordinary. These include processing flags, issuing suspensions, acting as a point of contact between staff and the community, investigating vote fraud, and managing disputes, among other things. You can read more at
[A Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/)
on the Stack Overflow Blog for a general overview.

### What do we expect of moderators?

In terms of time commitment, not a ton. Here on Emacs.SE, the moderation workload isn't huge. A few minutes a day is quite enough time to dedicate to moderator activities, for the most part. In terms of temperament, we're generally looking for people who can communicate well, keep their cool, and evaluate things from an objective standpoint. Having a decent grasp of Emacs and Emacs Lisp is a definite plus, as well as having previously shown involvement in the moderation and upkeep of the site (such as helping with the review queues and flagging).

### How do I participate in the election?

There are two main ways you can participate in the election: by nominating yourself, and by voting.

During the nomination period of the election, which lasts two weeks, any user with 300+ reputation and in good standing (i.e. has not been suspended in the past year) can nominate themselves. You'll have to write a nomination post on the election explaining why you think you'd be a good moderator and why people should vote for you. People can leave comments on your nomination with concerns or questions for you.

After the nomination phase, if there are more than 10 candidates, there will be a primary in which people will vote up or down on candidates. The top 10 candidates after the primary - or all of them, if there is no primary - then move to the election phase.

During the election phase, any user with 150+ reputation can vote in the election. You order any candidates you want to vote for in order of preference. (If your top choice for candidate is eliminated, your vote is transferred to the next candidate in your order of preference.)

When the election is over, the top candidate is elected as moderator and will be granted a diamond.

Remember, this post isn't a nomination thread - save your nomination for the election itself! This is meant as a heads-up that the election is happening, and to make sure that everyone's up to speed on how an election works. Feel free to ask any questions about moderation or the election process - someone should be able to answer them. This includes any questions you might have for the current moderator team - we'll be hanging around and can answer questions.

Good luck to anyone planning on running!

Comment: Well done. I wish diamond moderators on other sites would give their communities pre-election material like this! Do you know at least in which month the question collection / nomination period would begin?